# Run cleanup code without affecting $?

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a function that creates a temp file.I want the function to delete the temp file before it exits, but I want this cleanup to not effect the $? of the last command in the function

i.e.

```
function doSomething {
  TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
  commandthatmightfail ${TMPFILE}
  rm ${TMPFILE}
}

doSomething
echo $? # should output the result of the commandthatmightfail line
```

Currently I'm achieving this as below:

```
function doSomething {
  TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
  commandthatmightfail ${TMPFILE} && \
  rm ${TMPFILE} || { 
    rm ${TMPFILE} 
    false
  }
}
```

Which works but is messy. (It would also return false if the rm failed for some reason, but thats probably not a bad thing)

I think it could also be done by storing $? in a variable and then returning it after the cleanup, but I don't think that is much cleaner.
Is there a better way?

N.B. In my scenario I only really care about a zero vs non-zero return

I did investigate using bash's `trap RETURN` but it didn't seem to be appropriate to this use-case

Answer (score 0):

> I think it could also be done by storing $? in a variable and then returning it after the cleanup, but I don't think that is much cleaner. Is there a better way?

No, but having an explicit `return` *is* much cleaner and easier to understand than trying to make it magically happen via `trap` (especially to future maintainers who will be trying to understand the function several years later). The same pattern is frequently used in other languages such as C.

```
doSomething() {
    local r=0 tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    commandthatmightfail "$tmpfile"; r=$?
    rm -f "$tmpfile"
    return $r
}
```